# Finding Difference in dates in SQL Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-3.0

I have a varchar column in sql database which stores in the format (dd//mm/yyyy). I want to find difference between the System Date(ie. when a website is hit)and the column where i have stored date in (dd/mm/yyyy) and display the results of 2 columns of a table in a grid view. Can you please help in this.?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman : SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**DATEDIFF()**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) function.
Syntax

```
DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)
```

In your query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,CAST(dateColumn as datetime),CAST(TodaysdateColumn as datetime)) as dateDiffColumn
```

Edit

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(datetime,dateColumn,103),CONVERT(datetime,TodaysDateColumn,103)) as dateDiffColumn
```

This gives difference in dates in terms of number of days.
Then you can bind calculated column to Gridview column.

```
<asp:BoundField Text='<%#Eval("dateDiffColumn")%>' runat="server">
```

Comment: i neew to find difference in the format of dates as dd//mm/yyyy since i have stored this in db. also how to get system time in this format in query. I wont display calculated value in grid. Instead using calculated value i will display other column . So how can i put this in where condition?

Comment: difference in dates in form of dd/mm/yy ? Consider 02/21/2014 - 02/25/2014 . Should it be 02/04/2014 ? This is not correct. Difference between two dates is expressed in terms months,days,hours etc.

Comment: i want differnce in days only. Consider date i have stored as 15/03/2014 and System.Datetime.now as 14/03/2014 i want 15/03/2014-14/03/2014 as 1 (ie diff in days).

Comment: ok , i got it. You must be getting error conversion failed ..because CAST gives error for dd/mm/yyyy format. Instead use CONVERT() as shown in edited post above.

Comment: i dont have todaysdatecolumn specifically in db. I have to capture systemtime how to do that ?

Comment: @m hasan : I tried with some sample date with the above query. It returns only 0. If I use GETDATE() function it returns default value 41710.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the date string into a DateTime variable using `DateTime.ParseExact`. You can then compare the two dates as DateTimes and get the difference.

Comment: can u please exactly say how to put in SQL Statement as i need to build query in GridView